# Import datas in R - different currencies

Tags: r

I have to import some datas from Yahoo! finance to R. 
For example I have to import in R datas about *Roche Holding (AG)* ([Roche Yahoo! link](https://it.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=RHO5.DE)) and *The Goldman Sachs Group, Inc. (GS)* ([Goldman Yahoo! link](https://it.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GS)).

My problem is that *Roche Holding (AG)* datas are in euros and datas about *The Goldman Sachs Group, Inc. (GS)* are in dollars.

Now to import my datas in R I'm using:

```
Goldman_Sachs.z = get.hist.quote(instrument="GS", start=date.start,
                                 end=date.end, quote="AdjClose",origin="1970-01-01",
                                 provider="yahoo",compression = "m", retclass="zoo")
```

Is possible to import these datas just in dollars or must I implement a function in R to make this job?

And in the second case how can I choose the exchange rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Roche Holding is also traded on [NASDAQ OTC](http://www.google.com/finance?q=OTCMKTS%3ARHHBF) and you might therefore be able to obtain the current share price in USD, the proper way to handle such situations is to retrieve the data from the main market (which is the [Swiss Stock Exchange in Zurich](http://www.google.com/finance?q=SWX%3ARO) in this case) and calculate the value in dollars using the current exchange rate. The problem with OTC values is their low trading volume which may result in inaccurate prices.

To obtain the exchange rate of the CHF/USD Forex pair you can use the `quantmod` package:

```
library(quantmod)
getFX("CHF/USD")
tail(CHFUSD,1)    
#           CHF.USD
#2016-04-16  1.0332
```

The price in EUR does not seem to be a suitable choice in this case, but since you mentioned that you are looking at a market where Roche Holding is traded in EUR you may use in the same way `getFX("EUR/USD")`.

To download the EOD data from the Swiss Stock Exchange I would recommend using

```
Roche_CH <- getSymbols("SWX:RO", src ="google", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

or

```
Roche_CH <- getSymbols("RO.SW", src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Suppose today the currency exchange of EUR/USD is 1.13004 and I use it to make my conversions. It means I use 1.13004 (today currency exchange) to convert the adj Close of Roche Holding, for example on 18/01/2016 when the currency exchange of EUR/USD was different. In this way could I lose datas consistency? Maybe it is better to use the average of currency exchange of EUR/USD in my period of time (for example from 2000 to 2010). What do you think?

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana With  `getFX()` you obtain a time series, just as with `getSymbols()`.  In the answer above I used `tail(CHFUSD,1)` only to display the most recent value of the exchange rate. You can take the exchange rate of a specific day and use the quote of the stock of that same day to convert its value into the corresponding currency. It is a rather simple vectorized multiplication, although some preprocessing may be required to match the dates. Forex markets are open more frequently than stock markets.

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana More simply put: The value of a share of a foreign market depends on both, the share price and the exchange rate. Usually both values change on a daily basis. I would not use average values but instead calculate the value each day on the basis of these two quantities. Hope this clarifies your question.